# How to change launcher icons according to Numix theme?

Tags: 14.04, launcher, themes, icons

I recently installed *Numix* theme for my ubuntu 14.04.

After installing and upgrading I rebooted my system and the theme worked fine but after some time whenever I start my Ubuntu machinet the colors of the theme remains intact but the launcher icons and taskbar icons gets restored to defaults.

It takes 2-3 time rebooting to get the theme icons (Numix circle icons) back.

How to solve this problem?

Commands used:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:numix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install numix-gtk-theme numix-icon-theme
```

Tried `apt-get update` countless times.

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there: open Unity Tweak Tool (get it if you don't already have it), click on 'Icons', and you should find Numix-circle.